# Prove that if $\nabla f(\overline{x})=\overline{0}$ for all $\overline{x}\in D_f$, then $f$ is a constant function.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have a problem with the next exercise:

Let $f:D_f\subset\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function with $D_f$ open and connected set.

Prove that if $\nabla f(\overline{x})=\overline{0}$ for all $\overline{x}\in D_f$, then $f$ is a constant function.

Is it true if $D_f$ is not connected?

Ok. I have the following:

Since for all $\overline{x} \in D_f$ $\nabla f(\overline{x})=\overline{0}$  then $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0} \displaystyle\frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h}= 0 $ and $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0} \displaystyle\frac{f(x,y+h)-f(x,y)}{h}=0$

Also since $D_f$ is an open and connected set, then, is a connected by paths set. 
Pick $a,b\in D_f$, then, there exist a collection of points $x_1, x_2, ..., x_{n-1}\in D_f$ such that the segment containing them, joins $a$ with $b$. Then, we can consider the directional derivative over the poligonal formed by the $x_i$. Here, the derivative is zero because the directional derivative is $\nabla f\cdot u$.

Can I conclude with this?

Comment: $f$ could be locally constant (and thus not necessarily constant) if it isn't connected. Do you have access to path integrals at this point?

Comment: The definition of the derivative will not be sufficient. You should use the mean value theorem (or an integral).

Comment: Without the mean value theorem, this exercise is (to my knowledge) not doable. With the mean value theorem, it is a standard exercise in familiarity with MVT. Of course, if the domain is not connected, then this is not true, as the function can take different values in different connected components of the domain, and yet have derivative zero everywhere it is defined.

Comment: Since $D_f$ is open and connected, then, is connected by paths. Now, take $a,b\in D_f$. Now, there exist a collection of points $z_i$ such that $[a,z_1]\cup[z_2,z_3]\cup...\cup[z_n,b]\subset D_f$ . I think in use the theorem "Let $f:D\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$" such that $D$ is open and convex set. If the partial derivatives respect all variables there exist and for all $a,b\in D$ there exist a $\xi$ such that $f(b)-f(a)=\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(\xi)(b-a)$. But the problem is that your $D_f$ is not convex.

Comment: Somehow, you need to go from the derivative being zero to the function  being constant. That is all that is missing.